Getting error with obspy reading reftek130 files on python 3.13.0 windows 11
I have some problems to read reftek130 files on python 3.13.0 & windows 11 with obspy.
Although it has to work before reinstalling windows 11 & VS code & Python.
I did not understand the cause.
I reinstalled many python versions from 3.11.9 to 3.13.0 and no positive result i did not understand the cause.
Please I need help...
here is an example of my code:
from obspy import read
#cat=read('https://examples.obspy.org/COP.BHZ.DK.2009.050') # it works properly
#cat=read('C:/Localiser_Seisme/FichierRtpd/20241119/202411190044119150_TROT_TT_00-01.SAC') # even with this converted file (sac) it works properly
cat=read('C:/Localiser_Seisme/FichierRtpd/20241119/044519915_0002BF20_BCA4_TROT.rt') # but with this origin reftek130 file it gives error
print(cat)
cat.plot()

This is the message error on pyscripter:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Localiser_Seisme\LocaliserSeisme_Py_Ver_02\Signal\module1.py", line 7, in <module>
    cat=read('C:/Localiser_Seisme/FichierRtpd/20241119/044519915_0002BF20_BCA4_TROT.rt')
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\util\decorator.py", line 297, in _map_example_filename
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\stream.py", line 208, in read
    st = _generic_reader(pathname_or_url, _read, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\util\base.py", line 658, in _generic_reader
    generic = callback_func(pathnames[0], **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 232, in fun
    return caller(func, *(extras + args), **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\util\decorator.py", line 208, in uncompress_file
    result = func(filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\stream.py", line 251, in _read
    stream, format = _read_from_plugin('waveform', filename, format=format,
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                       headonly=headonly, **kwargs)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\core\util\base.py", line 423, in _read_from_plugin
    list_obj = read_format(filename, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\io\reftek\core.py", line 100, in _read_reftek130
    rt130 = Reftek130.from_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\io\reftek\core.py", line 148, in from_file
    rt._data = _initial_unpack_packets(string)
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\io\reftek\packet.py", line 256, in _initial_unpack_packets
    result['time'][:] += [_get_nanoseconds_for_start_of_year(y)
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
  File "C:\Users\Foued\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\obspy\io\reftek\util.py", line 44, in _get_nanoseconds_for_start_of_year
    year += 2000
OverflowError: Python integer 2000 out of bounds for uint8


looks like a bug in the library. file an issue with whoever maintains the library.

Thanks for your replay, is there any solution to fix this bug ??

ok it worked the solution is from https://github.com/wrefgtzweve the problem was on  the  numpy version pip install numpy==1.26.4  the latest version after 2.0.0 isn't compatible.
